# Implementing hashtable with Python but remove function failed with interesting bug

Tags: python, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a hashtable with python, here are my codes:

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self, key, value, next=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class HashTable():
    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity = 10
        self.buckets = [None] * self.capacity

    def _hash(self, k):
        hashsum = 0
        for c in k:
            hashsum += ord(c)
        return hashsum % self.capacity

    def put(self, key, value):
        bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
        node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
        if not node:
            self.buckets[bucketIndex] = Node(key, value)
            return
        prev = node
        while node is not None:
            if node.key == key:
                node.value = value
                return
            prev = node
            node = node.next
        prev.next = Node(key, value)

    def get(self, key):
        bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
        node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
        if not node:
            return None
        while node is not None:
            if node.key == key:
                return node.value
            node = node.next
        return None

    def remove(self, key):
        bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
        node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
        prev = Node(None, None, node)
        while node is not None and node.key != key:
            prev = node
            node = node.next
        if not node:
            return None
        value = node.value
        prev.next = prev.next.next
        return value
```

As above, it implemented put, get and remove functions. Put and get functions work as expected, but removing the first node in the bucket will fail.

Here is a quick way to reproduce.

```py
hashTable = HashTable()
hashTable.put('a', 111)
hashTable.get('a')  # return 111 as expected.
hashTable.remove('a')
hashTable.get('a')  # should return None, but return 111 instead.

# Removing other nodes in the same bucket will work
hashTable.put('C', 222)  # 'C' and 'a' will collide in this case
hashTable.get('C')  # return 222 as expected.
hashTable.remove('C')
hashTable.get('C')  # return None as expected.
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with call by ref? It is beyond my knowledge.

---

**Edit:**
Previously my remove function is like this:

```
def remove(self, key):
    bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
    node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
    prev = None
    while node is not None and node.key != key:
        prev = node
        node = node.next
    if not node:
        return None
    value = node.value
    if not prev:
        node = node.next  # ** here **
    else:
        prev.next = prev.next.next
    return value
```

This should be logically correct, but `node = node.next` does not change `buckets[bucketIndex]`. This is what actually puzzles me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a logic error in remove: You create a dummy `prev` in case the first element has the correct key and the loop body is never executed. In that case, there's no point in changing the `next` of the dummy to the second element. Instead, you need `self.buckets[bucketIndex]` to point to the second element.

```
    def remove(self, key):
        bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
        node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
        prev = None
        while node is not None and node.key != key:
            prev = node
            node = node.next
        if not node:
            return None
        if prev is None:
            self.buckets[bucketIndex] = node.next
        else:
            prev.next = node.next
        return node.value
```

Comment: Thanks! Previously I was trying `node = node.next` instead of `self.buckets[bucketIndex] = node.next`, but it doesn't work either. Do you know why?

Comment: That's not how Python works. `self.buckets[bucketIndex]` references an Object, which as a Node. `node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]` creates a reference to the same object with the identifier `node`, not coupled to `self.buckets[bucketIndex]` at all. `node = node.next` creates a new reference to the Node that is referenced by `node.next`, with the identifier `node`, which replaces whatever was called `node` before in the local namespace. Variable assignment never modifies existing objects (not to confuse with `__setitem__` operations).

Answer (score 1):

When removing first node you're actually not doing anything to it, you are redefining `prev.next`, but `self.buckets[bucketIndex]` stays exactly the same.

`prev.next = prev.next.next` works for all deletions from the middle of the chain, so you should add a separate handling for the start of the chain:

```
    def remove(self, key):
        bucketIndex = self._hash(key)
        node = self.buckets[bucketIndex]
        prev = Node(None, None, node)
        while node is not None and node.key != key:
            prev = node
            node = node.next
        if not node:
            return None
        value = node.value
        if not prev.key: # start of the chain
            self.buckets[bucketIndex] = node.next
        else: # middle of the chain
            prev.next = prev.next.next
        return value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added a follow up in my original question: the remove() was previously using `node = node.next` instead of `self.buckets[bucketIndex] = node.next`, but that doesn't work either. Do you know why?